# What port is mapped to the FQDN of an Azure Container Instance when multiple ports are opened?

Tags: azure, azure-container-instances

Title basically says it. The official MS documentation only says that you can connect to the container via the FQDN. So I assumed that when I open one port it would connect me to that port of the container. But what happens when I open more than one port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FQDN (fully qualified domain name) doesn't include port, so your container would be exposed via the combination of FQDN and whatever ports you open. For example:

- http://something.somewhere.azurecontainer.io:8080 (Postgres pgadmin web interface)
- something.somewhere.azurecontainer.io:5432 (Postgres DB engine)